# Including HTTP ACTION in Rest HATEOAS Spring Boot LinksTo

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I was doing some reading on recommended HATEOAS implementations from Microsoft and stumbled upon this

```
{
    "orderID":3,
    "productID":2,
    "quantity":4,
    "orderValue":16.60,
    "links": [
        {"rel":"product","href":"https://adventure-works.com/customers/3", "action":"GET" },
        {"rel":"product","href":"https://adventure-works.com/customers/3", "action":"PUT" }
    ]
}
```

I agree adding action to our hypermedia links would be a worthy addition but can't get around it?

Any recommendations on how to do this in Spring Boot ?

Comment: https://youtu.be/o4cc6KzNrpI?t=1970 (starting from 32:50) Oliver's talk may answer why there is not `action` value.

Comment: @yejianfengblue not sure where in the video - from his examples of Hateoas forms it looks like he wants to have actions in links

Comment: Either 1. at 33:50 use [CURIE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#mediatypes.hal.curie-provider) to provide a separae link to find documentation describing the link in `_links`, or 2. use [HAL-FORMS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#mediatypes.hal-forms) to documentation about the link in the `_templates` section. In the seond case, the `action` is not in the `_links` section but is documentated as `_templates.xx.method`

Comment: I found out my first comment is misleading. I mean the `_links` doesn't have a `action` value, but the `action` or `method` value should be found in a separate link with CURIE or in another inline section named `_template`

Comment: thanks  @yejianfengblue - i think now i'm clear :)